# jquery-traversing: select -> option -> text

Tags: jquery, select, text, traversal

I want to compare a variable with a select -> option -> text selected in order to change the "selected" attrib, here is my code, it works but I think is not the best way to write it, excuse my English, I used google translate for help hehehehe :

```
var lista = 'example 1'; 
$("#id option").each(function(){
  if($(this).text() == lista){
    $(this).attr('selected','selected');
  }
});
```

here's the html:

```
<select id="id" >
  <option value="0" >example 1</option>
  <option value="1" >example 2</option>
</select>
```

here's a few attempts

```
$('#id option:eq("'+lista+'")').attr('selected','selected')

$("#id option[text='"+lista+"']").attr('selected','selected')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of looping through each, you can try this:

```
var lista = 'example 1'; 
$('#id option:contains(' + lista + ')').attr('selected', true);
```

or

```
$('#id option:[text="' + lista + '"]').attr('selected', true);
```

Works just as well. It just depends if your variable `lista` will need to be an exact match or just a partial one.

Comment: Second option is perfect, i will need to be exactly match, i think that I was pretty close hehehee

Comment: @Victor Are you sure? :) I don't know why, but the code works only if the colon is present ... See here: http://jsfiddle.net/YbfqZ/1/

Comment: @Victor Are you saying that you accidentally placed the colon at that position, only to find out that it only works that way? That is hilarious `:)`

Comment: The reason for that behavior is that your colon breaks the selector for `querySelectorAll` because it isn't valid. As such, it defaults to Sizzle, which will tolerate the colon, even though it technically isn't supported (which means it could break in the future). I'm guessing Sizzle will check for both *attributes* and *properties*. As such, it won't find a `text` attribute, but it will find the `text` property (as the one used in my answer).

Comment: ...borrowing the fiddle from @Šime Vidas, [here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/YbfqZ/3/) that demonstrates that Sizzle will match a property instead of just an attribute with its `attribute-equals` selector.

Comment: @Andy Question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009572/jquery-selector

Comment: This helped me as well. Why such complicated code for such a simple thing ('init)

Comment: Can i get the option that begins with something?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with what you have, jQuery will be doing more-or-less the same under the hood.

You could use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter) if you want to chain it all together:

```
var lista = 'example 1'; 
$('#id option').filter(function () { 
    return $(this).text() == lista; 
})[0].selected = true;
```

[`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) might work for you but it works like a wildcard match, e.g. *cat* would match *category*:

```
var lista = 'example 1'; 
$('#id option:contains(' + lista + ')')[0].selected = true;
```

Comment: I need a case insensitive contains. Is this possible?

Comment: @Kees: you would have to go the `filter()` route and use a regular expression [`test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) with the `i` modifier.  If you get stuck, ask a question; that sort of thing will get you an answer in a matter of minutes.

Comment: Yeah, I used the filter. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

Your way is pretty efficient, but could be made a little more so like this:

```
var lista = 'example 1'; 
$("#id option").each(function(){
    if( this.text == lista ){
      this.selected = true;
      return false;
    }
});
```

This uses native properties so it will be faster.

- `.text` property gives the text content of the `<option>` element
- `.selected` sets the selected property
- `return false;` will break the loop once one is selected, so it doesn't needlessly continue

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$("#id option").attr('selected', function() {
    return this.innerHTML === lista;
});
```

Comment: I believe the OP was just looking for an optimization to his own code.

Comment: @Victor Yes I didn't notice that

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably too late.

```
var lista = 'example 1';
$('#id option[text="' + lista + '"]').attr('selected', true);
```

This is about 97% faster then

```
var lista = 'example 1';
$('#id option:contains("' + lista + '")').attr('selected', true);
```

check performance log at http://jsperf.com/selector-performance-00000

Comment: While you're right that the first selector will generally perform better, part of the reason for the performance difference is likely that the `[text=...]` version isn't matching any elements if your browser supports `querySelectorAll`. This is because `querySelectorAll` will look for a `text` *attribute*, which the `option` elements don't have.